# Python Tkinter grid not working with classes

Tags: python, tkinter

how do i change the position of the buttons with the grid system ??

I had it working without classes.

when i run the program it ignores the grid settings...

i want to use the grid system but it doesn't work.

this is how it looks now:

[image]

But i want something like this:

[image]

thanks in advance

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory


class Frame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        self.options = {'padx': 5, 'pady': 5}
        super().__init__(container)
        self.grid(padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.NSEW)


class Button(Frame):
    def __init__(self, container, text, col, row, opt):
        super().__init__(container)
        self.path = tk.StringVar()
        self.button = ttk.Button(self, text=text)
        self.button['command'] = self.selectpath
        # HERE
        self.button.grid(column=col, row=row, sticky=tk.W, **opt)

    def selectpath(self):
        path_ = tk.filedialog.askdirectory()
        self.path.set(path_)


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        tk_width = 330
        tk_height = 150
        self.geometry(str(tk_width) + 'x' + str(tk_height))
        x_left = int(self.winfo_screenwidth() / 4 - tk_width / 2)
        y_top = int(self.winfo_screenheight() / 2 - tk_height / 2)
        self.geometry('+{}+{}'.format(x_left, y_top))
        self.resizable(False, False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    window = Frame(app)
    selectbutton = Button(window, 'hello',  2, 0, window.options)
    selectbutton = Button(window, '1hello',  1, 1, window.options)
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: _but it doesn't work_ explains nothing, what exactly doesn't work? how should it look and how it looks?

Comment: I want to change the position of the buttons but they are not changing their position

Comment: what do you think this does: `self.grid(padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.NSEW)`? It grids the frame but doesn't specify where, you provide column and row only to the buttons, so in that frame they are correctly put in their respective columns, but the frame that they are contained in is gridded without argument, so basically you might as well use `pack` for the frame, you need to pass the column and row to the `Frame` as arguments, the `Button` itself can be just `pack`ed

Comment: Since there is only one button in the frame, it will be at the top left corner of the frame no matter what row and column are set.

Comment: you use `grid` with wrong widget. You put every `ttk.Button` in new `Frame` so `self.button.grid` creates new grid in every `Frame` - and because there is only one `ttk.Button in this grid so it displays it in the same place. Empty rows and columns in grid have no width nor height. You would have to put `ttk.Button` directly in main `Frame` or you have to use `self.grid` instead of `self.button.grid` to put new `Frame` in main `Frame` in correct place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `grid` with wrong widget. You put every `ttk.Button` in new `Button(Frame)` so `self.button.grid` creates new grid in every `Button(Frame)` and it puts `ttk.Button` in this new frame, not in main grid in main `Frame`. Because there is only one `ttk.Button` in this grid so it displays it in the same place. Empty rows and columns in grid have no width nor height.

And every `Button(Frame)` uses `self.grid` without `column=` and `row=` so it put every `Button(Frame) in new row in main` Frame`.

You would have to use `column=`, `row=` with `self.grid` instead of `self.button.grid`

```
        # put `ttk.Button` in current `Button(Frame)`
        self.button.pack()  
        
        # put current `Button(Frame)` in main `Frame`
        self.grid(column=col, row=row, sticky=tk.W, **opt)
```

---

Minimal working code:

[image]

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory


class Frame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        self.options = {'padx': 5, 'pady': 5}
        super().__init__(container)
        self.grid(padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.NSEW)


class Button(Frame):
    def __init__(self, container, text, col, row, opt):
        super().__init__(container)
        self.path = tk.StringVar()
        self.button = ttk.Button(self, text=text)
        self.button['command'] = self.selectpath
        
        # put `ttk.Button` in current `Button(Frame)`
        self.button.pack()  
        
        # put current `Button(Frame)` in main `Frame`
        self.grid(column=col, row=row, sticky=tk.W, **opt)

    def selectpath(self):
        path_ = tk.filedialog.askdirectory()
        self.path.set(path_)


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        tk_width = 330
        tk_height = 150
        self.geometry(str(tk_width) + 'x' + str(tk_height))
        x_left = int(self.winfo_screenwidth() / 4 - tk_width / 2)
        y_top = int(self.winfo_screenheight() / 2 - tk_height / 2)
        self.geometry('+{}+{}'.format(x_left, y_top))
        self.resizable(False, False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    window = Frame(app)
    selectbutton = Button(window, 'hello' , 2, 0, window.options)
    selectbutton = Button(window, '1hello', 1, 1, window.options)
    app.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:**

Maybe you wouldn't have this problem if you would create `Button(ttk.Button)` instead of `Button(Frame)`

```
class Button(ttk.Button):

    def __init__(self, container, text, col, row, opt):
        super().__init__(container, text=text, command=self.selectpath)
        self.path = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.grid(column=col, row=row, sticky=tk.W, **opt)

    def selectpath(self):
        path = tk.filedialog.askdirectory()
        if path:
            self.path.set(path)
```

---

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory


class Frame(ttk.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.options = {'padx': 5, 'pady': 5}
        self.grid(padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.NSEW)


class Button(ttk.Button):

    def __init__(self, master, text, col, row, opt):
        super().__init__(master, text=text, command=self.selectpath)
        self.path = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.grid(column=col, row=row, sticky='w', **opt)

    def selectpath(self):
        path = tk.filedialog.askdirectory()
        if path:
            self.path.set(path)


class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        tk_width = 330
        tk_height = 150

        x_left = int(self.winfo_screenwidth()  / 4 - tk_width  / 2)
        y_top  = int(self.winfo_screenheight() / 2 - tk_height / 2)

        self.geometry(f'{tk_width}x{tk_height}+{x_left}+{y_top}')

        self.resizable(False, False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    window = Frame(app)
    selectbutton = Button(window, 'hello' , 2, 0, window.options)
    selectbutton = Button(window, '1hello', 1, 1, window.options)
    app.mainloop()
```